# How to package html files into jar/war with buildr?

Tags: wicket, embedded-jetty, buildr

I'm working on an embedded Jetty + Wicket app and I'm using buildr. Right now, Buildr isn't including the HTML files (which are in the main source folder, alongside my *.java files) in the jar. How can I tell buildr to include them in the compilation/package step?

Thanks for the suggestions, I think I'm close. Maybe the question I should be asking is how to get the .HTML files into the right place in the target/classes/ subdirectory? I've confirmed that if I can get the .html files in the target/classes folder, package(:jar) archives them. I'm going to start looking at that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Thanks for the suggestions, I think I'm close. Maybe the question I should be asking is how to get the .HTML files into the right place in the target/classes/ subdirectory? I've confirmed that if I can get the .html files in the target/classes folder, package(:jar) archives them. I'm going to start looking at that.

It sounds like what you want to do, then, is treat the java source paths as resource paths. Here's [how](https://ncisvn.nci.nih.gov/svn/psc/branches/releases/2.9-stable/tasks/inline_resources.rake) I do that in a project I converted to buildr after it was already pretty large:

```
# Uses before_define to default all projects to including their resources from
# src/main/java instead of src/main/resources (& similar for test) if
# those source directories exist
module InlineResources
  include Buildr::Extension

  before_define do |p|
    [
      [p.resources, p._("src/main/java")],
      [p.test.resources, p._("src/test/java")]
    ].each do |res, path|
      if File.exist?(path)
        res.from(path).exclude("**/*.java")
      end
    end
  end
end

class Buildr::Project
  include InlineResources
end
```

This will put the *.html files in `target/resources` and from there they will be added to the package.

Comment: Awesome, I'll be able to try this tomorrow. The resources get bundled alongside the .class files then?

Comment: Yes, the paths are preserved.

Answer (score 0):

Buildr take contents in src/main/webapp folder for war file contents. You need to keep the html files inside that.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where in the WAR they need to go, but generally you can do something like this:

```
package(:war).include(_(:source, :main, :java, "**/*.html"))
```

The `:war` package is a specialization of the `:jar` package, which is a specialization of the `:zip` package, so you can use any of the [documented methods](http://buildr.apache.org/packaging.html) for `:jar` or `:zip` on a `:war`, too.

Comment: Close! I'm packaging a jar and when I use the .include(...) as suggested it puts my .html files in the root of the jar. I think Wicket expects them alongside the .class files (in com/package/whatever/)

Comment: in buildr you can do smth like this: package(:zip).path("#{PACKAGE_NAME}/bin").include(_("target/scripts/*")) - the path part allows you to set "root" where include will happen

Comment: @atamur that's also close :) But that solution is dumping everything into a single directory. I might have some html files in com/p1/*.html and some in com/p1/c1/*.html and some in com/p2/*.html. I need them all to keep their relative paths in the jar's "classes" subfolder.